# Google Map Marker Not Showing

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

I have this codes but when im trying to display the marker its not showing but i can view my current location. but at first these codes are working properly.

```
package com.fatima.lokalngrizal;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class RizalMap extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener  {


GoogleMap googleMap; 
LatLng myPosition;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rizal_map);
        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        //GoogleMap object from fragment
        googleMap = fm.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of google map
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);


        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //retrieve provider..
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // kuha current location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if(location!=null){
        // kuha latitude ng location mo 
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // kuha longitude ng location mo 
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // creating latlng ng location mo ngayun
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

         myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("You are HERE !"));

    }
}
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I even try this codes still the maker is not showing. i just want to see some markers to my map

```
 map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(new LatLng(14.7748641,121.2433147))
          .title("Montalban Town Center")
```

Answer (score 2):

This probably means your location variable is still null, so your codes inside the if statement are not been called. Your location manager probably need to call the `requestLocationUpdates` method.

For for information about Location Manager, you can check out [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html).

Or [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html) about Google Maps Markers.

For now, you can also try it without location manager, below are the sample code:

```
 Marker hamburg = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(53.558, 9.927))
        .title("Hamburg"));
 Marker kiel = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(53.551, 9.993))
        .title("Kiel")
        .snippet("Kiel is cool")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

  // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
  googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(53.558, 9.927), 15));

  // Zoom in, animating the camera.
  googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same problem.

When I was getting the latlang value was

```
LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

Then I made my latitude value negative and it worked,

```
LatLng location = new LatLng(-1*latitude, longitude);
```